# Notification after killing a topology in storm in java

Tags: java, apache-storm

When you kill a topology, is there a way to be notified that it is actually killed in java?

For my integration test, I start a local cluster with my topology in @Before, then I kill it in @After. This way, my topology never gets "dirty" with other tests running on it at the same time even if it could take a lot of time to run all the tests.

As for instance in windows, you can't shutdown cleanly a cluster (that shutdowns everything), is there a way to be sure that the topology is killed as I don't want to start a new topology if the other one is still alive.

I have already reduced Config.TOPOLOGY_MESSAGE_TIMEOUT_SECS to 0 to force kill workers as soon as possible, still I have to wait some arbitrary time to be sure the topology is killed before submitting the new 'clean' one for the next test.

Answer (score 1):

To me this sounds more like a problem of isolating your integration tests than knowing when a topology is really dead. There should be no problem with running multiple topologies simultaneously on the same cluster, and those old workers, even if they have not fully spun down, should not interfere with new workers that spin up as part of a newly deployed topology.

If the concern is about workers accessing resources outside the Storm cluster, you're probably better off trying to isolate those resources between tests than to ensure all Storm workers have died.

Comment: I'll try that, Running my topology only once per test suite, cleaning external systems between each test.